# Laravel Three State Login Attempt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

As default Laravel Login attempt method returns bool but I want to modify it and getting another result if user exists but user's status is passive.
I do not want to change any code in laravel vendor directory. I can write my own login method in LoginController like `AuthenticatesUsers::login()` easily but the problem is `SessionGuard::attempt()` has own lifecycle, it is not a trait that LoginController uses it.

Following is original version of `SessionGuard::attempt()` method.

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = false)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {

        if ($login) {
            $this->login($user, $remember);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // If the authentication attempt fails we will fire an event so that the user
    // may be notified of any suspicious attempts to access their account from
    // an unrecognized user. A developer may listen to this event as needed.
    if ($login) {
        $this->fireFailedEvent($user, $credentials);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note:

```
$credentials = [
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'status_id' => 1
           ];
```

But I want to remove status_id field and I want to show message to users if user's status_id is not 1.

Basically I just want to override `SessionGuard::attempt()` method, something like this.

```
public function attempt(array $credentials = [], $remember = false, $login = false)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)) {
        //User exists but user's status_id is not 1
        if($user->status_id != 1)
            return 2; // 2 for passive accounts
        if ($login) {
            $this->login($user, $remember);
        }

        return 1; //for active accounts
    }

    // If the authentication attempt fails we will fire an event so that the user
    // may be notified of any suspicious attempts to access their account from
    // an unrecognized user. A developer may listen to this event as needed.
    if ($login) {
        $this->fireFailedEvent($user, $credentials);
    }

    return 0; // for non exists acounts
}
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: We need more information. What do you mean with `any code in laravel framework` ? What should happen in both functions? You can just manually login the user inside your controller function so you don't have to overwrite them.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English I assume I could not explain my problem. Ihave just edited my question. I hope this time is better than older version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it inside your login function of your controller (normally the LoginController)

You first get the user with a unique email. Then you check if the account has the variable. If yes you can try to login the user, if not you can throw an error.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

        public function login(Request $request) {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }
        $user = App\User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();

        if ($user && $user->status_id == 1 && $this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct answer but needs some improvements and fixing syntax errors. I have tried to edit but it says edit queue is full. Maybe someone needs it too so could you add these line;`use AuthenticatesUsers {
        login as protected traitLogin;
    }`and use `return $this->traitLogin($request);` instead of `Auth::attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']));`
Finally thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer. I used now the login function from the trait an modified the if statement. you can change the logic, for example if you want to show another message when the user is not activated, but this should work now.

Comment: I have already edited older version of your code for my project and it works too. Also I override the AuthenticatesUsers:: sendFailedLoginResponse method in LoginController so I can send any message for any situation. There is no change in  AuthenticatesUsers or SessionGuard. Thank you again.